# Permissions to view certain databases

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 4 databases,

Database 1
Database 2
Database 3
Database 4

I have a client that I want to give access to my DB instance. If I give it full access it will see all 4 databases.

I just want him to be able to "see" Database 1 and Database 4 and that the other 2 do not appear

I understand that there are read permissions, and this makes it possible to see all the databases, but not the content, which each table has, but it is possible that when that user connects to my instance, they can only see Database 1 and Database 4, and that the other two cannot be seen?

Comment: There are no really good solutions for this. By default `public` has the `VIEW ANY DATABASE` permission, and if you revoke that, the only way to see a database is if you're connected to it, or if you are the owner of it. The latter implies far more permission than merely being able to see the database, however, since you would be able to do anything with it -- including dropping it, which is not usually desirable. Separating databases by giving them actually separate server instances is the most secure, but is more difficult to manage and may consume additional resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a Login for that user

in SSMS in the Object Explorer go to Security/Logins then right mouse "new login"
In the login properties go to User Mapping and select for each database if and what he is allowed there
Any database that is "unticked" there he will not see, and if he would see it in some way he will not be able to connect

[image]

Comment: I have done what you told me, I have connected with the user, but I still see all the databases. It's true that I can't explore them, but I can see them, and that's not what I need, I just want two to be seen and all of them are seen.

Comment: I expected he would not be able to see them, sorry I don't have any other answer, let's hope someone else knows this better and will answer you

Comment: No problem, i will keep search

Answer (score 0):

Try the following - deny viewing any database to the specific login, they can still view DBs they are owner of:

```
Use master
go
Deny view any database to Login
go
Alter authorization on database::Login to Login
go
```