How could I give access of my local SQL database to an external user in SSMS
We have a Vendor who is trying to give me access to their local database through SQL Server Management Studio and I am just trying to help them out so that I can get the access sooner. They provided me with login credentials and I was able to connect but was unable to see the database, can anyone help me outlining the steps on how I can achieve the desired results and get the access. Thank You.
They created a user in SSMS and gave me credentials for that and I tried connecting, connection was successful but database was not visible.

Sounds like they gave you a server level ID to login as.  So you have access to the server.  They now need to grant you access to the database itself.

please have a look also here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71626149/permissions-to-view-certain-databases
